# Disable language detection for "Speak selection" on macOS accessibility

Tags: macos, accessibility

On macOS versions up to Catalina the "Speak selection" Accessibility feature only used the default voice, no matter what language the highlighted text was. From Big Sur onwards, Speak selection auto-detects the language and use that voice. Is there a way to disable this? I want it to always use the default English voice I selected, no auto-detection for anything.

Over the years of using Speak selection, I've learned to understand what the English voice is reading when it reads in my native language. Now it just defaults to Dutch 90% of the time, and the other 10% it switches between Russian, French, and English, which is really annoying.

I have tried forcing it by disabling the language auto-detection for the VoiceOver utility, but that doesn't do anything for Speak selection. I'm willing to mess around in .plist files if I have to. Whatever it takes!

Currently running Big Sur, but would like to upgrade to Monterey soon. Can't go later than that, my hardware don't support it. So if someone knows how to disable auto-switching for either Big Sur or Monterey, I'd be super grateful!